# CS0117: aspx page does not contain a definition for function

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I am using an aspx page, single file web form, to capture user input on the client side via a dropdown box and then modify available text box fields (simple example...if client selects dropbox item 1, then text box 1 is enabled; if client selects dropbox item 2, then text box 2 is enabled).

The dropbox html code looks like this and works perfectly with exception of event handler OnSelectedIndexChanged:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FAQ" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" Width="354px" AutoPostBack="true"          OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectedFAQ()" > 
        <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value="Default"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Text 1 Here" Value="FAQ1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Text 2 Here" Value="FAQ2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Text 3 Here" Value="FAQ3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The function selectedFAQ() is defined in the script section:

```
function selectedFAQ()
{
    //code to enable/disable text fields here
}
```

I have seen several different posts and answers to this issue, but it seems that the posts I have seen contained an aspx and aspx.cs file...my page is the single web form.

I also want to mention that the page is not my creation, I am simply trying to add additional functionality to it.  And finally, there is a "inherits" tag that references a 3 year old dll that I do not have the code for.

If this issue has been addressed, please point me to the correct question/answer and thanks.  If not, please assist if able.  I can provide any additional code if needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently have is a subscription to a postback event. That is, function that should handle change of index in server side code. However your fucntion is actually a javascript one and executes on a client side. To call that, you need to assign a different attribute of the drop down control:

```
onchange="selectedFAQ();"
```

And remove handling of `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, you won't be able to define a server side handler without code behind access anyway.

Comment: `javascript:` is meaningless; that isn't a URL.

Comment: Thanks Andrei...that appears to have resolved my issue.  Do I give you points or close out this question?

Comment: @jhs, if that helped the best thing to do is to mark the answer as accepted - that will indicate for others that this answer indeed solves the issue in question

Comment: @SLaks, true, removed